# json deserialize into class and access results in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm deserializing json into a class and it seems to work, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the results.  I am instantiating the class and then attempting to place the deserialized json into it but then the class containers are out of reach.  I'm not sure how to work with the individual containers.

Here is the class

```cs
public class geocodes
{
    public Boolean outcome { get; set; }

    public double xcord { get; set; }

    public double ycord { get; set; }
}

class jsonresult
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Spatialreference spatialReference { get; set; }
        public Candidate[] candidates { get; set; }
    }

    public class Spatialreference
    {
        public int wkid { get; set; }
        public int latestWkid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Candidate
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
        public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
        public Extent extent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public float x { get; set; }
        public float y { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attributes
    {
    }

    public class Extent
    {
        public float xmin { get; set; }
        public float ymin { get; set; }
        public float xmax { get; set; }
        public float ymax { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I populate the class with

```cs
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    jsonresult results = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<jsonresult>(responseString);
    ...
}
```

I'd like to do a foreach through every root container or even spatial reference (because it will often return more than one)  I would even be happy if I just pulled that portion of the json into a class, but I can't figure out how.

Here is the json:

```
{
 "spatialReference": {
  "wkid": 2253,
 "latestWkid": 2253
 },
 "candidates": [
  {
   "address": "816 Example ST",
   "location": {
   "x": 13288754.574891519,
    "y": 288356.77197193989
  },
   "score": 100,
  "attributes": {

  },
   "extent": {
    "xmin": 13288098.406912517,
    "ymin": 287700.60399293725,
    "xmax": 13289410.742870521,
    "ymax": 289012.93995094253
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please share with us a sample json.

Comment: I'll add the comment in the orignal.

Comment: Remove the surrounding `jsonresult` class and use simply: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responseString)`

Comment: Thanks Peter!  This was really helpful.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark i as the ansewr.

Comment: I've just left a post please check that. I've just realised that I've used Json.Net in the comment even though you are using System.Text.Json. In the post I've used System.Text.Json.

Comment: I checked it before posting anything so no worries, it worked fabulously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is the extra (unnecessary) layer: `jsonresult`.

`jsonresult` does not have any property that's why *System.Text.Json* can not correctly deserialize data into it. In other words after `JsonSerializer` has created a new instance of the `jsonresult` class by calling its parameterless constructor it can not assign the read value to any of its public properties.

---

If you remove the `jsonresult` surrounding class and use `RootObject` during `Deserialize` then after `JsonSerializer` created a `RootObject` instance then it can populate its properties with data by using reflection (and name based matching).